# Postgres with Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I have docker-compose.yml as:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_USER=docker"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - "./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
```

In folder sql, I have a .sql file containing:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mytestdb;
CREATE DATABASE mytestdb;
\c mytestdb;
```

docker-compose gets postgres container up and running. But when I connect to the server via pgadmin, I see no database with name 'mytestdb' created. Instead I see one with name 'docker'.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you will have to write a .sh script.

Comment: When you edited your SQL file before first docker-compose up or after? It is just shot in the dark, but maybe you first created docker image and then updated .sql file. Maybe it is worth to check logs one by line. Additionally I assume you didn't share with us your Docker file and docker-entrypoint.sh file and maybe something else is missing. So it is hard to tell until you do not share full setup with us.